# Overlay only on image element if we have image, h1 and h2 element in same div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get overly effect on image only and a different hover overlay effect on image only, but it is not working with following structure.

I want to get effect on image class rather than wrapping image in a separate div which i know works but is it possible to make it work with the structure in example:

```css
.container{display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr ;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width:100%;}
.blog-item-wrapper{background-color:#f6f6f6;}
.blog-image{width:100%; display:block;}
.blog-image::after {
    content: ""; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #eaee44, #33d0ff);
    opacity: .7;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="blog-item-wrapper">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="blog-image" src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/nature">
    <h1>This is Title of blog</h1>
    <h2>dd/mm/yyyy</h2>
  </a>
 </div>
<div class="blog-item-wrapper">
  <a href="#">
    <img class="blog-image" src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/animal">
    <h1>This is Title of blog</h1>
    <h2>dd/mm/yyyy</h2>
  </a>
 </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Your question is vague. Please add more detail.  Do you want on hover: overlay changes changes color? is it suppose to start with an overlay(::after)? What does the Headings(h1,h2) have to do with the image? should they be overlay as well?  If all you are looking for is when hover on image show overlay. when hover over area containing image or title/time show overlay. I have the solution ready to post.

Answer (score 1):

You can hover on the parent and change the inner class attributes

*.blog-item-wrapper:hover .blog-image*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <style>
            .container {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
                grid-template-rows: auto auto;
                grid-gap: 10px;
                background-color: #fff;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .blog-item-wrapper {
                background-color: #f6f6f6;
            }
            .blog-image {
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
                background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #eaee44, #33d0ff);
                opacity: 0.4;
                z-index: 1;
            }
            /* if hover on image only 
            .blog-image:hover {
                background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #44eeaa, #d0afa0);
                opacity: 0.8;
                z-index: 1;
            }
            */
            /*  hover on wrapper - title, time or img */
            .blog-item-wrapper:hover .blog-image {
                background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #44eeaa, #d0afa0);
                opacity: 0.7;
                z-index: 1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="blog-item-wrapper">
                <a href="#">
                    <img
                        class="blog-image"
                        src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/nature"
                    />
                    <h1>This is Title of blog</h1>
                    <h2>dd/mm/yyyy</h2>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="blog-item-wrapper">
                <a href="#">
                    <img
                        class="blog-image"
                        src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/animal"
                    />
                    <h1>This is Title of blog</h1>
                    <h2>dd/mm/yyyy</h2>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```